# inequality proof using calculus

Tags: calculus, inequality

let $a,b,c,d >0$, $ab=cd$, and $a<b$. show that $a<c,d<b \iff c+d<a+b$.
I show that if direction as follows

Suppse that $c \leq d$, and let $ab=cd=l$. Then
$c+d<a+b$ is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
  \frac{l}{d}+d<\frac{l}{b}+b.
\end{equation}
Since $f(x)=\frac{l}{x}+x$ is an increasing function on $x \geq \sqrt{l}$ the last inequality is true.

Now for the other direction, I got nowhere. I want to show that for $a,b,c,d >0$, $ab=cd$, and $a<b$ the inequality $c+d <a+b$ implies that $0<a<c<b$ and $0<a<d<b$.

Any help is appreciated. I don't want an answer but a hint to the right direction would be great.

Comment: The other direction still has $ab=cd$ and $a<b$ as conditions

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes they are still satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose by way of contradiction that $d\geq b.$ Then since $b\leq d$ and $a<(b\leq)d,$ the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) gives us:

$$d^2 + ab \geq ad + bd.$$

Therefore,

$$d+c = d + \frac{ab}{d} = \frac{d^2+ab}{d} \geq \frac{db+ad}{d} = a+b,$$

contradicting the fact that $c+d<a+b.$

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just have a question about the rearrangement inequality. You seem to use the inequalities $d \geq b$ and $d >a$ to show that $d^2+ab \geq ad+bd$. Doesn't the inequality $d>a$ has to be $d \geq a$ to use the rearrangement inequality?

Comment: I'm confused by your comment. If $d>a$ then surely $d\geq a.$